# Formatting a text file java

Tags: java, formatting

I am trying to format a text file. I want to delete all the new line characters except the ones that are used to start a new alinea. By that I mean if the line in the text file is whitespace I want to keep it but all the other newlines need to be deleted.

here is what I have so far:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Formatting {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("give file name: ");
        String filename = in.next();
        File inputfile = new File(filename);
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(inputfile);
        String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("NEW " + filename);

        while(reader.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = reader.nextLine();


            if (line.length() > 2 && line.contains(newline)) {
                String replaced = line.substring(0,line.length()) + ' ';
                out.print(replaced);
            }
            else {
                out.print(line + ' ');
            }

        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
    }
}
```

however now my first if statement never gets executed. Every newline just gets deleted.

Can anybody help me here? It would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This may help you , read comments to  get idea what is the use of each line .

// 3. compress multiple newlines to single newlines

```
            line = line.replaceAll("[\\n]+", "\n");


            // 1. compress all non-newline whitespaces to single space

            line = line.replaceAll("[\\s&&[^\\n]]+", " ");


            // 2. remove spaces from begining or end of lines
            line = line.replaceAll("(?m)^\\s|\\s$", "");
```